# Android studio error <uses-permission >

Tags: android-studio

Estoy realizando un proyecto en React-native sin embargo tuve que involucarme con android studio para integrar la sdk de facebook, y me arroja un error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui esta el codigo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="false"

  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent" />


  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

ademas de que me solicita despues integrar este fragmento de codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede que los permisos los estés poniendo dentro de un nodo incorrecto del `Manifest`. Ponlos **al principio**, asegurando que están fuera de cualquier nodo que no sea el   de `<manifest>`.  [Aquí puedes ver una estructura completa de cómo debería ir el `Manifest`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html?hl=es-419)  Luego, esto sobra: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent" />`, pues ya diste permiso para ello más arriba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La definición de permisos debe ser realizada dentro de `<manifest>` y afuera de `<application>`

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En realidad ya definiste el pemiso, dentro de `<manifest>` y afuera de `<application>`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

entonces puedes eliminar este:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
    tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent" />
```

Comment: si lo note apenas :), pero muchas gracias